# Meaning of 'embedded someone into'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> We actually **embedded a CIA deputy into FBI operations** so that we could
>   really share the intelligence.

In this sentence, what exactly means 'embeded a CIA deputy into'?

Comment: It's probably the sense ***embedded = planted***, corresponding to definition 10 in [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plant) *If an organization **plants** someone somewhere, they send that person there so that they can get information or watch someone secretly.* But whereas this use of ***plant*** always implies ***secrecy***, that might not be the case with ***embedded***, so we'd need more context to have an opinion on that. Plus of course the speaker might very well wish to be *deliberately* imprecise on that specific point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short what it means is: 
In an FBI operation (containing few FBI members) a member from CIA(CIA deputy) has been added. Here the word "Embedded" is used because an FBI Operation generally only consists of FBI members and not a person from CIA

Generally speaking the word "Embedded" is used to express a scenario where something(A) is put in side/together with something else(B), where B generally may not include/contain A.

Example:

- "a gold ring with nine embedded stones"
- "the Victorian values embedded in Tennyson's poetry"
- "you can embed the videos into a blog post."

Answer (score 1):

So, ***to embed*** something is to place it within another things. An embedded computer system is a computer system that is within something else - a television, a fridge, a camera. If a precious stone is embedded in rock, it is within that rock and will be more difficult to extract.

The same can be said of people within organisations or situations. We talk about *embedded reporters* during military conflict. These are reporters who are travelling with soldiers, seeing (within limits) what they see. If a CIA deputy is embedded into the FBI, they are situated 'within' the FBI for their work; rather than working in the CIA offices, they work in the FBI offices, operate day to day alongside the FBI personnel.

For bonus points, it's worth noting that this is an example of *liaison* between organisations.